# EPPlus Excel download from MVC causes an out of memory exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, epplus, epplus-4

I'm using the following code to send an EPPlus package to the client as an Excel file in asp.net MVC.  However, I'm having an issue with large files throwing OutOfMemoryException exceptions.

```
public class ExcelPackageResult : ActionResult
{
    public ExcelPackage ExcelPackage { get; set; }
    private string _fileName;

    public ExcelPackageResult(ExcelPackage excelPackage, string fileName)
    {
        ExcelPackage = excelPackage;
        _fileName = fileName;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ClearContent();
        ExcelPackage.SaveAs(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);
        context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format(@"attachment;filename=""{0}.xlsx""", _fileName));
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();

        context.HttpContext.Response.End();

        ExcelPackage.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The issue is at the line: `ExcelPackage.SaveAs(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream);`

I've also tried:
`context.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(ExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray());`

Is there a way to stream the response directly from the ExcelPackage instead of allocating a block of memory for it before sending?

Comment: How much data is in the excel file? (rows and columns)

Comment: rounded up, 190,000 rows X 40 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats probably going to be too much data for EPPlus unfortunately.  See this for some background:

[EPPlus, handling big ExcelWorksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216729/epplus-handling-big-excelworksheet/28220127#28220127)

One thing that has worked for some people is compiling to 64 bit if that is an option:

[EPPlus Large Dataset Issue with Out of Memory Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787443/epplus-large-dataset-issue-with-out-of-memory-exception/29912563#29912563)

Otherwise, you will have to do something like create the xml files yourself or some sort of VBA integration.  Neither are pretty.

Comment: It looks like you're correct.  However, there is a pull request currently open on the EPPlus project site that looks to address the memory consumption issue: http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/kazy111/EPPMemoryOptimization/contribution/8725

Comment: @RyanHerbert - Looks like that could help if they accept it.  It will probably not "solve" the problem unfortunately in the sense that since it is 32 bit there is still a "realizable" limit if they excel table is big enough.  But that for sharing that post - looks interesting!