# EPPlus 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: asp.net, excel, epplus

I am trying to open a 38MB Excel File using *EPPlus v4.0*, I am able to pass it to the *ExcelPackage* variable but when I'm trying to get the workbook from that variable, it causes me a '*System.OutOfMemoryException*'.

Here's my code:

```
    Dim temppath = Path.GetTempPath()
    Dim filenamestr As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.GetRandomFileName())

    Dim tempfilename As String = Path.Combine(temppath, filenamestr + ".xlsx")

    fileUploadExcel.SaveAs(tempfilename) 

    Dim XLPack = New ExcelPackage(File.OpenRead(tempfilename))
    GC.Collect()
    If File.Exists(tempfilename) Then
        File.Delete(tempfilename)
    End If

    Dim xlWorkbook As ExcelWorkbook = XLPack.Workbook 'the error shows here
```

I'm stuck. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably hitting the ram limit as that is a big file.  If you have the option to compile to 64 bit you might be able to solve the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29912563/1324284

But if you can only compile to x86 there is not a whole lot you can do with epplus.  You will have to either use a different library or build the XML files for excel yourself:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26802061/1324284

Comment: Sadly, I can only compile to x86... Good thing I already started with a workaround. Thanks anyway!

Comment: For future usage, can you suggest any libraries that I can use for large files? Tried ClosedXML, still no luck. I used EPPlus because it is recommended by many and is user-friendly, but most of my work involves manipulating large Excel files. Thanks again!

Comment: @Aethlen The free all have their issues (even the paid ones do too).  See if this helps (I cannot recommend anything specific to your situation I am afraid): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444522/import-and-export-excel-what-is-the-best-library?rq=1

Comment: I guess I'll have to install Excel on our server then. Thanks anyways!

Comment: What about if my data hit 64-bit RAM limit?

Answer (score 0):

[Essential XlsIO](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio) is an option for loading large Excel files using .NET.

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million US Dollars in revenue). The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.