# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown while Export to Excel using EPPlus in C# windows application

Tags: export-to-excel, epplus

I am getting error while export to excel large amount of data using EPPLUS library in C# windows application.
Dataset contains one table with 120 columns and more than 200k rows.

It is throwing 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.

```
protected void GetDailyTransactionDump_New()
{
    try
    {
        DataSet dsGetData = new DataSet();
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        string Date = "";
        string filename = "Transaction_Dump.xlsx";
        ht.Add("@report_date", Date);
        bll.GetDataset("Usp_Get_TransactionDump", ht, CommandType.StoredProcedure, out dsGetData); 
        //dsGetData retruns 120 cols and 200k rows

        ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dsGetData.Tables[0], true); //getting exception here
        package.SaveAs(new FileInfo(filename));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34831519/1048799

Comment: The data is too large to process the entire thing in memory with EPPLUS.  You might consider saving it as a .CSV instead (which can be opened in Excel).  Use a Streamwriter to do that, or use CSVHelper.

Comment: Thanks it is working on 64 bit platform.