# EPPlus throw exception Error saving file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I use EPPlus for work with Excel. I save data with pictures (qty 1635). When saving, it throw exception "Error saving file". In InnerException there is "An exception of type" System.OutOfMemoryException"".
that StackTrace

```
in System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
in System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
in System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
in OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.CountingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\Shared.cs:line 813
in OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zlib.ZlibBaseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) in d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\Zlib\ZlibBaseStream.cs:line 160
in OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zlib.DeflateStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\Zlib\DeflateStream.cs:line 617
in OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Crc.CrcCalculatorStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\CRC32.cs:line 710
in OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.ZipOutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\ZipOutputStream.cs:line 1290
in OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackagePart.WriteZip(ZipOutputStream os) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\ZipPackagePart.cs:line 149
```

RAM = 8gb. Max size picture is 200kb, average size ~70kb

in line `in OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.CountingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\Shared.cs:line 813`
values are 8096, 0, 8096. MemoryStream.Length = 161412349
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EPPlus Large Dataset Issue with Out of Memory Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787443/epplus-large-dataset-issue-with-out-of-memory-exception)

Comment: I use one worksheet

Comment: Is your executable 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: 32bit. 64bit we can't use