# How to add a pivot table filter field using EPPlus and C#

Tags: c#, pivot-table, epplus

I'm creating an Excel file using the [EPPlus library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and C#.

In this Excel file there is a sheet with pivot table to which I'd like to **add a filter field** like in this manually created Excel sheet (Country):

[image: Excel pivot table filter field]

How can I do this using EPPlus?

Comment: Seems impossible for Epplus to do page filters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26142249/169714

Answer (score 4):

I did not see your code, but you can do something like this.

```
var ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["index of your worksheet"];
var pivotTable = ws.PivotTables[0]; //assuming that you only have 1
var pivotField = pivotTable.Fields["Country"];
pivotTable.PageFields.Add(pivotField); // should add field into desired place
```

Hope it´s a little bit helpful. Don´t forget to save your excel file at the end.